# DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded

Tags: javascript, cors, webgl

I have the following error when using the ShortPixel CDN solution on this website: [https://worksite.artonice.com/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

> Chrome: THREE.WebGLState: DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded.
> FireFox: THREE.WebGLState: DOMException: The operation is insecure.

This happens when the slider on top is animated, and the images are taken from CDN instead of being local. The CDN images are like this:

[https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/spai/q_lossy+ret_img/https://worksite.artonice.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/artonice_DSC6199_k.jpg](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I have searched through similar aticles and all mention the CORS issue but he CDN resources have the correct CORS header: `access-control-allow-origin: *` I also tried adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the image tags of the slides (by modifying them manually before the JS is executed, as they are generated by a WP plugin) but this didn't solve.

What could be the issue?

Thanks!